# How to get the properties of the `move` event from an atom electron's BrowserWindow?

Tags: node.js, electron

The BrowserWindow has a `move` event as stated here:
https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-move

But how do I get the coordinates where it moved?
I do this:

```
mainWindow.on( "move", function( event ) {
    console.log( event );
});
```

But I get this:

```
{ preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  sender: 
   BrowserWindow {
     _events: 
      { blur: [Function],
        focus: [Function],
        'devtools-opened': [Function],
        closed: [Function],
        move: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     devToolsWebContents: [Getter] } }
```

Now what? what are the properties of the event? no event properties are documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get them like this:

```
mainWindow.on( "move", function( event ) {
    console.log( event.sender.getBounds() );
});
```

Output:

```
Object {x: 622, y: 159, width: 800, height: 600}
```

Comment: Thanks! how could I found about other events properties, is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Sure. About event properties, that's the thing...i think most BrowserWindow event objects don't have any properties, just notify the event.